# ¿Como crear un numero de serie en base al ultimo registro de mi base de datos?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy tratando de crear un numero de serie en el sistema que tengo en base al ultimo registro de mi base de datos, el problema es que me esta fallando la consulta en el método para poder obtener este ultimo dato.

El método que uso para poder generar el numero de serie

```
   public int GenerarNumero()
    {

        var pedido = bd.Pedido.Where( x => x.Vigente == true).LastOrDefault();//aqui trato de obtener el ultimo resgitro de mi base de datos pero me da error en la peticion de linq
       
        pedido.Numero = pedido.Numero + 1;
        return pedido.Numero;
    }
```

Los numero de serie ya ingresados están hechos con Random

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternativamente puedes usar la función max

```
public int GenerarNumero()
{
   pedido.Numero = bd.Pedido.Max(a=> a.Numero) +1;    
}
```

No veo mucho sentido en colocar `.Where( x => x.Vigente == true)`, esto puede ocasionar repetir el número, pero dado el caso sería

```
 pedido.Numero = bd.Pedido.Where( x => x.Vigente == true).Max(a=> a.Numero) +1;
```

Comment: hice algo parecido que me funciono, cree una lista ordenando desde menor a mayor, tomando el ultimo numero y darle +1